# CSS text is overriding. How to remove text override?

Tags: html, css

In the code, you can see there are multiple jobs. There is class defined top space of job area. Now apply this rule only for the first job then after add 24 px margin for 2nd, 3rd n... Jobs. How can I achieve my expected result? In the job area, I can add X number of jobs. Please apologize me if I made any grammatical mistake.

```css
.Job_area {
 position: absolute;
 top: 829px;
}

.Description {
 position: absolute;
 left: 187px;
 width: 1050px;
 height: 24px;
 margin-top: 36px;
}

.Size {
 position: absolute;
 left: 1237px;
 width: 272px;
 height: 24px;
 margin-top: 36px;
}

.Quantity {
 position: absolute;
 left: 1509px;
 width: 320px;
 height: 24px;
 margin-top: 36px;
}

.RPU {
 position: absolute;
 left: 1830px;
 width: 323px;
 height: 24px;
 margin-top: 36px;
}

.Amount {
 position: absolute;
 left: 2156px;
 width: 350px;
 height: 24px;
 margin-top: 36px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Job_area">
   <div class="Description">
      <p style="text-align:center">Job Work(Business Card, 350 GSM Valvet Lamination, Front Back)</p>
   </div>
   <div class="Size">
      <p style="text-align:center">92x54</p>
   </div>
   <div class="Quantity">
      <p style="text-align:center">1000 nos.</p>
   </div>
   <div class="RPU">
      <p style="text-align:center"><i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i> 0.85</p>
   </div>
   <div class="Amount">
      <p style="text-align:center"><i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i> 850.00</p>
   </div>
   <div class="Description">
      <p style="text-align:center">Job Work(Business Card, Name Print)</p>
   </div>
   <div class="Size">
      <p style="text-align:center">-</p>
   </div>
   <div class="Quantity">
      <p style="text-align:center">2 Nos.</p>
   </div>
   <div class="RPU">
      <p style="text-align:center"><i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i> 150.00</p>
   </div>
   <div class="Amount">
      <p style="text-align:center"><i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i> 300.00</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you make everything `position: absolute` is it necessary, can you give snapshot of what you want to achieve

Comment: @Rahul No, it's not necessary. I just want that every new job comes in the new line.

Comment: I think you should use table for this layout then

Comment: If you remove all the css from this snippet, it works as desired.